# Using JwtSecurityToken with HttpClient

Tags: c#, jwt

I am trying to use a JWT token to query an OpenApi endpoint with a `HttpClient`. I have been trying to do this for a while now with multiple attempts of different things like `Base64` encodings and just putting the JWT token raw into the Authorization header, but the endpoint splits back a `403 Forbidden` with "Authentication failed" every time. The validation of the JWT works fine and is done with `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`:

```
public JwtSecurityToken ValidateCurrentToken(string token)
{
    var jwksJson = GetKeyInfo();
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var keyset = JsonWebKeySet.Create(eveJwksJson);
    
    var tokenParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
    tokenParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
    tokenParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
    tokenParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
    tokenParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
    tokenParameters.ValidateActor = false;
    tokenParameters.ValidIssuers = new List<string>{ "host1", "host2" };
    tokenParameters.IssuerSigningKey = keyset.Keys.First();

    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenParameters, out validatedToken);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Token is not valid: " + e.Message);
    }

    var securityToken = (JwtSecurityToken) validatedToken;
}
```

But I cant figure out what to add to the Authorization header in this section:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri, JwtSecurityToken token)
{
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", <WHAT TO PUT HERE>);
    httpRequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = uri
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
}
```

Some have suggested that I tried `urlBase64` encode the `JSON` data from the token, but no result. Documentation for this all has something to do with services and I can seem to find any that applies to my issue.

Comment: <WHAT TO PUT HERE> Your JwtSecurityToken token from your signature. You can check to token to make sure it's valid at jwt.io

Comment: @GHDevOps I'm going to need more specifics, I'm sorry. JwtSecurityToken has no Token property. When I look at the JwtSecurityToken data I can use, I don't really know what I am looking for. I'm not very strong in JWT, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: What is the problem. What  the error have you received?

Comment: @Serge I get 403 Forbidden, with an "Authentication failed" message in content. I am quite sure it is because I do not to the right thing in the Authorization header. I can call the API on its some endpoints without Authorization required and that works just fine.

Comment: I am afraid that the API  neeeds a special authorization.  If it is  only jwt it returns 401 errror.

Comment: @Serge You were sort of correct! There was a known bug in it after I browsed the endpoints GitHub if you had some specific user settings set, that could generate a to long of a JWT token. I reconfigured and now it works. Nothing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the token, the `ValidateCurrentToken` method just does the validation. The string parameter `token` is your JWT token which contains three parts concatenated with a dot, they are Header, Payload and Signature. Header and Payload are base64 encoded. For example, it should look something like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

So you already have the value you need to use, you don't need to convert `JwtSecurityToken` into a string. Just use the value in the `token` parameter in the Authorization header. Make sure you leave a blank space between `Bearer` keyword and the token.

You can refer to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction) for more info about JWT tokens and how they work.

Comment: So I just take that string value and add it directly to the Authorization header?

Comment: yes @evilfish it should work as far as I understand from looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to < WHAT TO PUT HERE > Take a look at this class [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet) and see if it´s help in your case. The sugestion is to use the [WriteToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.writetoken?view=azure-dotnet#system-identitymodel-tokens-jwt-jwtsecuritytokenhandler-writetoken(microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-securitytoken)) method to get a string of the JWT in compact serialization form.

```
new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
```